# Macro VBA para organizar registros em relatório de ponto funcionário

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Preciso organizar os dados que estão em ordem cronológica para um relatório que está em data. A Macro deve primeiro iterar pela coluna CRM, depois pela coluna DATA e organizar os registros de mesma data na mesma linha.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei a seguinte Macro, mas a condição `If Str(Datarel.Value) = Str(Databd.Value) Then` parece não funcionar.  Obrigado!

```
     Sub macro()

    Dim i, j, k

    Set Id = Range("B1")
    Set Datarel = Range("B3")
    Set Idbd = Range("H2")
    Set Databd = Range("I2")
    Set Horabd = Range("J2")


    For i = 1 To 1
        For j = 1 To 31        
            For k = 1 To 12

            Datarel.Select

            If Str(Id.Value) = Str(Idbd.Value) Then
                If Str(Datarel.Value) = Str(Databd.Value) Then
                    If Str(Datarel.Offset(0, 1).Value) = "" Then
                        Datarel.Offset(0, 1).Value = Horabd.Value
                    ElseIf Str(Datarel.Offset(0, 3).Value) = "" Then
                        Datarel.Offset(0, 3).Value = Horabd.Value
                    ElseIf Str(Datarel.Offset(0, 4).Value) = "" Then
                        Datarel.Offset(0, 4).Value = Horabd.Value
                    ElseIf Str(Datarel.Offset(0, 5).Value) = "" Then
                        Datarel.Offset(0, 5).Value = Horabd.Value
                    End If
                End If
            End If            

            Set Idbd = Idbd.Offset(1, 0)
            Set Databd = Databd.Offset(1, 0)
            Set Horabd = Horabd.Offset(1, 0)
            Range("G1") = Range("G1") + 1
            Next k
            Set Datarel = Datarel.Offset(1, 0)
            Set Idbd = Range("H2")
            Set Databd = Range("I2")
            Set Horabd = Range("J2")
        Next j        

        Set Id = Id.Offset(34, 0)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Os dados de entrada da tabela não condizem com os dados de saída, favor fazer um [mcve]

Comment: Editei e tentei deixar mais claro. Obrigado.

Comment: Aparentemente o código não tem erro nenhum. Em qual linha dá a mensagem de erro? Execute utilizando a tecla F8 para ver qual linha gera o erro.

Comment: Na verdade não está dando erro. Descobri que o "If Str(Datarel.Value) = Str(Databd.Value) Then" não está funcionando quando a condição é verdadeira. Sera que é algum problema com o Str que não funciona com o tipo Data? Não sei como isso funciona no VBA.

Comment: Em vez de Str, utilizei CDate e passou a dar certo. Porém o Else If é é executado mesmo se o If anterior é verdadeiro, como se fosse um If seguido.

Comment: Teoricamente, se o ElseIf está sendo executado, a condição no ElseIf anterior não foi atendida. Execute o código linha a linha com o F8 e posicione o cursor do mouse em cima das variáveis para ver seu conteúdo. Exemplo, colocando o cursor em cima de Horabd.Value, o VBA mostra o valor.

Comment: Os "Ifs" If Str(Datarel.Offset(0, 1).Value) = "" Then deveriam ter sido escritos sem função de conversão. Datarel.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then Deu certo! gostaria de agradecer a colaboração de todos. Segue resposta com o resultado do código, que pode ser útil para criar um sistema de ponto no Excel, quando há uma lista de registros para ser organizada em um relatório de ponto.

Answer (score 1):

Solucionado! segue o resultado.

```html
Sub macro()

    Dim i, j, k

    Set Id = Range("B1")
    Set Datarel = Range("B3")
    Set Idbd = Range("H2")
    Set Databd = Range("I2")
    Set Horabd = Range("J2")


    For i = 1 To 1
        For j = 1 To 31
            For k = 1 To 12

            Datarel.Select

            If Str(Id.Value) = Str(Idbd.Value) Then
                If CDate(Datarel.Value) = CDate(Databd.Value) Then
                    If Datarel.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
                        Datarel.Offset(0, 1).Value = Horabd.Value
                    ElseIf Datarel.Offset(0, 2).Value = "" Then
                        Datarel.Offset(0, 2).Value = Horabd.Value
                    ElseIf Datarel.Offset(0, 3).Value = "" Then
                        Datarel.Offset(0, 3).Value = Horabd.Value
                    ElseIf Datarel.Offset(0, 4).Value = "" Then
                        Datarel.Offset(0, 4).Value = Horabd.Value
                    End If
                End If
            End If

            Set Idbd = Idbd.Offset(1, 0)
            Set Databd = Databd.Offset(1, 0)
            Set Horabd = Horabd.Offset(1, 0)             
            Next k
            Set Datarel = Datarel.Offset(1, 0)
            Set Idbd = Range("H2")
            Set Databd = Range("I2")
            Set Horabd = Range("J2")
        Next j

        Set Id = Id.Offset(34, 0)
        Set Datarel = Id.Offset(2,0)

    Next i
End Sub
```